# Laravel with JWT - How to make route group for routes that can be seen only if unauthenticated

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, jwt

So I am working on an Angular JS x Laravel project. I decided to use JWT tokens and I have some routes like register and login that must be accessible only if the user is not authenticated. Here is are my routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['before' => 'jwt.auth']], function () {
    Route::resource('api/user', 'UsersController');
    Route::resource('api/group', 'GroupsController');
    Route::resource('api/project', 'ProjectsController');
    Route::resource('api/lesson', 'LessonsController');

    Route::get('api/authenticate/user', 'AuthenticationController@getAuthenticatedUser');
    Route::get('/{any}', function ($any) {
        return view('index');
    })->where('any', '.*');

});

Route::post('api/register', 'AuthenticationController@register');
Route::post('api/login', 'AuthenticationController@login');

Route::get('/{any}', function ($any) {
    return view('guest');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

How can I make a route group for the routes outside the `jwt.auth` route group to be accessible only if the user in not authenticated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this on the frontend side with your angular controllers. Here is how I did it

```
//Controller used for the login page
whimAppControllers.controller('LoginController', ['userService', '$location', '$scope', '$http', function (userService, $location, $scope, $http) {

//Upon clicking the login button this function attempts to login in the user through the API
 $scope.login = function() {

    //Send the user supplied values to the userService in services.js when then attempts to POST to the API
    userService.login(
        $scope.login, $scope.userName, $scope.password,

        //Upon response, if successful return the user to the main page, else return error
        function(response){
            $location.path('/');
        },
        function(response){
            alert('Something went wrong with the login process. Try again later!');
        }
    );
}

//Clear out the fields on the login form
$scope.email = '';
$scope.userName = '';
$scope.password = '';

//If the user is already logged, redirect to the main page
if(userService.checkIfLoggedIn())
    $location.path('/');

}]);
```

At the bottom it checks to see if the user has already been assigned a JWT and if so it redirects to the homepage.

In my in my service.js file, the userService has this method to check for the JWT:

```
//Checks to see if token is present or not
function checkIfLoggedIn() {

    if(localStorageService.get('token'))
        return true;
    else
        return false;

};
```

I'm using LocalStorageModule to make the call to localStorageService:

```
var whimAppServices = angular.module('whimAppServices', [
'restangular',
'LocalStorageModule',
'ngFileUpload'
```

]);

I'm using angular-local-storage to store the JWT on the client: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage